# Lutris infinitely says "this game requires blizzard-battlenet-standard" when installing Diablo IV

Tags: 22.04, games, lutris

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.

When I try to install Diablo IV through lutris it tells me "this game requires blizzard-battlenet-standard. Would you like to install?". When I hit yes, it opens another dialog to install Battle.net, and when I hit install there, it opens another dialog that says "this game requires blizzard-battlenet-standard. Would you like to install?". I hit yes, and it opens the Battle.net installer dialog again....this goes on forever.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got the same issue. installed it from the lutris site . just look for this Blizzard Battle.net on the site. The link to that is https://lutris.net/games/battlenet/ hope this helps.